How to fill in all atoms in unit cell starting from a CIF file?
I am trying to write code that builds a unit cell with all atoms explicitly specified, starting from a CIF file of a molecular crystal.  The CIF files come from CSD.  My first try was to use Gemmi to read the file, and then apply symmetry to sites like this:
structure = gemmi.read_small_structure(cif_file)

for image in structure.cell.images:
    for site in structure.sites:
        fract = image.apply(site.fract)
        # add a new atom at fractional coordinates fract

This works on some files, but it turns out that many of the files in CSD contain sites which are transformed by the symmetry ops to other (also existing in the file) sites! Oops.
An example from the structure of benzene, BENZEN in CSD:
loop_
_symmetry_equiv_pos_site_id
_symmetry_equiv_pos_as_xyz
1 x,y,z
2 1/2-x,1/2+y,z
3 x,1/2-y,1/2+z
4 1/2-x,-y,1/2+z
5 -x,-y,-z
6 1/2+x,1/2-y,-z
7 -x,1/2+y,1/2-z
8 1/2+x,y,1/2-z

loop_
_atom_site_label
_atom_site_type_symbol
_atom_site_fract_x
_atom_site_fract_y
_atom_site_fract_z
C1 C -0.05690 0.13870 -0.00540
C2 C -0.13350 0.04600 0.12640
C3 C 0.07740 0.09250 -0.12950
H1 H -0.09760 0.24470 -0.01770
H2 H -0.24090 0.07940 0.22180
H3 H 0.13710 0.16310 -0.23120
C3D C -0.07740 -0.09250 0.12950
C2D C 0.13350 -0.04600 -0.12640
C1D C 0.05690 -0.13870 0.00540
H3D H -0.13710 -0.16310 0.23120
H2D H 0.24090 -0.07940 -0.22180
H1D H 0.09760 -0.24470 0.01770

Here for example the -x,-y,-z symmetry transforms C1 into C1D.
It seems the file contains a whole molecule (this is nice) but also contains some symmetries that transform part of the molecule onto another part (less nice).  What is the most general, reliable way to convert CIF files into a complete unit cell made up of whole molecules?
I don't have to use Gemmi specifically, this is more of an algorithmic/data convention question, but if there is existing code out there which reliably handles this I would be happy to use it.

+1 but your question was edited because of this rule: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/421/5. You can edit it again, as long as there's only 1 question, and that it doesn't look like there's any more than 1 question.

Gemmi developer here. I didn't realize it. I'll look into it, but probably not before the next month.

@marcin Thanks!

The simplest procedure that I can think of is to keep track of all atom positions and check that a given position is not occupied before adding a new atom. This check should account for periodic boundary conditions.
Here is your example expanded with such a check:
import gemmi

cif_file = 'benzen.cif'
structure = gemmi.read_small_structure(cif_file)
all_sites = structure.sites[:]

def pbc_distance(fract1, fract2):
    return structure.cell.find_nearest_pbc_image(fract1, fract2).dist()

def is_occupied(fract):
    return any(pbc_distance(site.fract, fract) < 0.1 for site in all_sites)

for image in structure.cell.images:
    for site in structure.sites:
        fract = image.apply(site.fract)
        # add a new atom at fractional coordinates fract
        if not is_occupied(fract):
            new_site = site.clone()
            new_site.fract = fract
            all_sites.append(new_site)
structure.sites = all_sites
structure.spacegroup_hm = 'P 1'
structure.make_cif_block().write_file('output.cif')


